# Get the compression information of input parquet file using Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, parquet, pyspark

I have a requirement, where I am reading the input parquet file and repartitioning into smaller files to reduce the size. The problem is, the compression type of input and output parquet file should match (by default pyspark is doing snappy compression). That should not happen. Suppose, if input compression type is gzip then output should be gzip or if input is snappy output should be snappy.

Is there any parameter so that I can set to match compression type.

Comment: `parquet-tools meta` output provides compression info. https://github.com/wesleypeck/parquet-tools

Comment: Are you aware that Parquet allows compression-type per column? This can get very tricky

Comment: @shay__ is there any way to check that

Comment: @mazaneicha parquet-tools is a separate package right which has a dependency pyarrow. Any idea using Pyspark, compression information can be checked?

Comment: You can use (java)  `ParquetFileReader.readSummaryMetadata`

Comment: @shay__ is there any way to get using python pyspark.

Comment: yes, google "pyarrow.parquet"